# Unable to return correct output from created function in JES

Tags: python, jython, jes

I am fairly new to jython and I am inquiring about creating a function that is dealing with a list. Basically what I am trying to do with the below function is create a function that will loop through the entirety of my list, then find the lowest value within that list and return the variable with the lowest number. Though, I keep getting a return of **function min at 0x26** everytime I execute the main() I receive the same message but it seems as if the **function min at 0x26** will count up **ex: 0x27, 0x28**... Not sure why this is. As my list only contains integers of minimum 0 to max 99.

Here is the sourcecode:

```
def min(dataset): #defining a function minimum, with input dataset(the list we are using)..
    min = dataset[0]
    for num in range(0, len(dataset)):
      if dataset[num] < min:
        min = dataset(num)
    return min
    minimum = min(dataset)
    print(str(minimum))
```

Here is the code in its entirety. Though, I currently have a way to find the min/max values in the list. I am looking to move towards a function, as I want to know how to correctly use a function.

```
def main( ):
  dataset = [0]
  file = open("D:\numbs.dat", "r")
  for line in file: #loop for writing over every line to a storage loc.
    num = int(float(line)) #converting int to string
    dataset.append(num) #appending the data to 'dataset' list
  max = dataset[0] #setting an imaginary max initially
  low = dataset[0] #setting an imaginary low initially
  for i in range(0, len(dataset)): #for loop to scan thru entire list
    if dataset[i] > max: #find highest through scan and replacing each max in var max
      max = dataset[i]
    if dataset[i] < low: #find lowest through scan and replacing each max in var max
      low = dataset[i]
  #printNow(dataset) #printing the list in its entirety
  #printNow("The maximum is " +str(max)) #print each values of lowest and highest
  #printNow("The lowest is " +str(low))

  def min(dataset): #defining a function minimum..
    min = dataset[0]
    for num in range(0, len(dataset)):
      if dataset[num] < min:
        min = dataset(num)
    return min
    minimum = min(dataset)


  print(str(minimum)) #test to see what output is.
```

As mentioned above, there is the for loop for finding max/min values. Though I tried doing the same exact thing for the function I am trying to create...

the contents of the numbs.dat can be found here (1001 entries):

**70
75
76
49
73
76
52
63
11
25
19
89
17
48
5
48
29
41
23
84
28
39
67
48
97
34
0
24
47
98
0
64
24
51
45
11
37
77
5
54
53
33
91
0
27
0
80
5
11
66
45
57
48
25
72
8
38
29
93
29
58
5
72
36
94
18
92
17
43
82
44
93
10
38
31
52
44
10
50
22
39
71
46
40
33
51
51
57
27
24
40
61
88
87
40
85
91
99
6
3
56
10
85
38
61
91
31
69
39
74
9
17
80
96
49
0
47
68
12
5
6
60
81
51
62
87
70
66
50
30
30
22
45
35
2
39
23
63
35
69
83
84
69
6
54
74
3
29
31
54
45
79
21
74
30
77
77
80
26
63
84
21
58
54
69
2
50
79
90
26
45
29
97
28
57
22
59
2
72
1
92
35
38
2
47
23
52
77
87
34
84
15
84
13
23
93
19
50
99
74
59
4
73
93
29
61
8
45
10
20
15
95
58
43
75
19
61
39
68
47
69
58
88
82
33
30
72
21
74
12
18
0
52
50
62
21
66
26
56
84
16
12
7
45
58
22
26
95
82
6
74
12
16
2
61
58
22
39
0
53
88
79
71
13
54
25
31
93
48
91
90
45
23
54
42
39
78
25
95
58
2
41
61
72
98
91
48
97
93
11
12
1
35
80
81
86
38
70
67
55
55
87
73
79
31
43
97
79
3
51
17
58
70
34
59
61
28
46
13
42
18
0
18
75
75
62
50
62
85
49
83
71
63
32
27
59
42
46
8
13
39
25
13
94
17
48
73
40
31
31
86
23
81
40
92
24
94
67
30
18
74
78
62
89
1
27
95
99
33
53
74
5
84
88
8
52
0
24
21
99
1
74
84
94
29
25
83
93
98
40
21
66
93
28
72
63
77
9
71
18
87
50
77
48
68
88
22
33
16
79
68
69
94
64
5
28
33
22
21
74
44
62
68
47
93
69
9
42
44
87
64
97
42
34
90
70
91
12
18
84
65
23
99
1
55
6
1
23
92
50
96
96
68
27
17
98
42
10
27
26
20
13
94
73
75
12
12
25
33
1
33
67
61
0
98
71
35
75
68
56
45
11
1
69
57
9
15
96
69
2
0
65
44
86
78
97
17
4
81
23
4
43
24
72
70
57
21
91
84
94
40
96
40
78
46
67
6
7
16
49
24
14
12
82
73
60
42
76
62
10
84
49
75
89
43
47
31
68
15
11
32
37
98
72
40
25
69
30
64
60
48
21
11
74
54
24
60
10
96
29
39
53
48
24
68
4
52
12
6
91
15
86
77
65
68
22
91
36
72
82
81
9
77
0
5
83
27
88
17
35
66
76
78
81
19
51
87
66
26
59
65
2
37
37
73
34
98
37
78
92
17
52
62
40
50
84
34
22
25
42
90
19
86
76
68
42
9
89
57
78
64
89
12
34
94
9
77
58
32
27
97
93
79
35
32
75
97
79
65
90
53
43
98
4
99
5
79
38
99
60
78
64
90
2
39
42
52
2
21
77
15
8
87
13
0
4
7
43
76
31
74
16
87
50
73
49
14
35
10
37
91
44
88
71
95
75
98
7
17
23
13
16
77
20
50
50
74
78
58
30
21
74
76
93
5
74
94
83
23
67
18
5
50
47
56
79
26
84
78
48
71
43
41
8
91
23
7
11
96
87
12
42
32
44
99
67
99
64
96
52
19
79
60
66
52
62
17
61
54
24
25
36
4
78
3
94
91
62
65
76
94
2
52
25
61
55
49
88
85
96
5
46
56
48
17
25
3
70
62
3
50
45
47
58
12
41
27
42
90
91
71
53
4
79
47
68
43
87
35
63
10
49
4
81
45
88
80
6
92
47
70
40
7
33
70
61
30
9
55
42
83
26
72
57
77
91
13
15
33
13
62
49
43
65
73
98
59
56
77
62
12
25
33
53
78
73
1
17
44
56
95
10
33
89
33
20
56
69
66
60
53
83
58
43
33
25
21
8
28
65
51
70
53
78
49
30
64
17
76
9
2
32
87
77
39
25
21
66
65
54
81
49
15
27
7
14
4
11
94
9
84
23
13
95
45
67
57
20
3
58
50
97
35
68
47
41
84
59
46
34
19
25
77
29
41
89
80
61
70
40
1
18
32
70
86
76
25
98
99
40
43
92
43
4
70
78
72
71
85
14
84
73
92
60
23
57
44
56
6
96
39
91
63
43
39
71
80
18
93
54
1
4
46
68
93
74
74
88
52
88
55
24
19
92
53
59
1
91
48
47**

Let me know what the heck I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: That is not the complete code. We cannot run it. The indentation looks bad too. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have uploaded the code in it's entirety as well as the contents of a seperate file needed for the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ohGosh welcome to stack overflow. You are almost there with the solution. There are few problems with your program

1) Nums.dat file contains just one line with numbers separated by spaces, not a new line(\n). In order to get the read the numbers from the file do the following

```
dataset = []                          #Create an empty list
file = open("D:\numbs.dat", "r")      #Open the file
for line in file:
     tempData = line.split(" ")       #Returns a list with space used as delimiter
     dataset = map(int, tempData)     #Convert string data to int
```

2) Wrong way to get data from a list in the min function

Use

```
min = dataset[num]
```

Instead of

```
min = dataset(num)
```

Fix this and your program will work. Cheers.